# MKMap Pin Colour

Tags: iphone, xcode, annotations, mkmapview

I am new to Xcode and basically I have an `MKMapView` and would like to add individual colours to each of my pins. I currently have marked pins with annotations.

LocationAnnotation.h:

```
@interface LocationAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

LocationAnnotation.m:

```
#import "LocationAnnotation.h"

@implementation LocationAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

@end
```

Each of my coordinates look like this in the 
MainMapViewController.h:

```
#define TheKingBill_LATITUDE 50.431379
#define TheKingBill_LONGITUDE -3.685495

 //Annotation

NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
LocationAnnotation * myAnn;

//The King Bill Annotation
myAnn = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = TheKingBill_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = TheKingBill_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"The King Bill";
myAnn.subtitle = @"Another Pub In Town";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

 //The Seven Stars Annotations
myAnn = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] init];
location.latitude = TheSevenStars_LATITUDE;
location.longitude = TheSevenStars_LONGITUDE;
myAnn.coordinate = location;
myAnn.title = @"The Royal Seven Stars Hotel";
myAnn.subtitle = @"Hotel In Town";
[locations addObject:myAnn];

 [self.MainMapView addAnnotations:locations];
```

Any ideas on what I need to add to make each pin coloured differently?

Thanks!

---

Okay so now I have a problem with my other map that links to this LocationAnnotation file. I also want to add colour pins to this. It would be ideal if the new code would be the same as my previous mapviewcontroller. Here is the code...

LocationAnnotation.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface LocationAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property int idNumber;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andSubtitle:(NSString *)subttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d andID:(int)idN;

@end
```

LocationAnnotation.m

```
    #import "LocationAnnotation.h"

    @implementation LocationAnnotation

    @synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle, idNumber;

    - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andSubtitle:(NSString *)subttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d andID:(int)idN
    {
        self = [super init];

        if (self)
        {
            self.title = ttl;
            self.coordinate = c2d;
            self.subtitle = subttl;
            self.idNumber = idN;
        }

        return self;
    }

    @end
```

MapViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

    @interface MapViewController : UIViewController

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *ClientMapView;

    @end
```

MapViewController.m

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "LocationAnnotation.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end


//The Dartmouth Inn Coordinates
#define DARTMOUTH_INN_LATITUDE 50.430036;
#define DARTMOUTH_INN_LONGITUDE -3.683873;

//Span
#define THE_SPAN 0.004f;



@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize ClientMapView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    //Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    //Centre
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centre;
    centre.latitude = DARTMOUTH_INN_LATITUDE;
    centre.longitude = DARTMOUTH_INN_LONGITUDE;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = centre;
    myRegion.span = span;

    //Set The Map View
    [ClientMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];


    //Annotation

    //1. Create A Coordinate for use with annotation

    CLLocationCoordinate2D dartLocation;
    dartLocation.latitude = DARTMOUTH_INN_LATITUDE;
    dartLocation.longitude = DARTMOUTH_INN_LONGITUDE;


    LocationAnnotation * myAnnotation = [LocationAnnotation alloc];
    myAnnotation.coordinate = dartLocation;
    myAnnotation.title = @"The Dartmouth Inn";

    [self.ClientMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I want to set each annotation individually so I can pick its colour. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here we are, your code with modifications :

LocationAnnotation.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface LocationAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property int idNumber;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andSubtitle:(NSString *)subttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d andID:(int)idN;

@end
```

LocationAnnotation.m

```
#import "LocationAnnotation.h"

@implementation LocationAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle, idNumber;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andSubtitle:(NSString *)subttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d andID:(int)idN
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.title = ttl;
        self.coordinate = c2d;
        self.subtitle = subttl;
        self.idNumber = idN;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

MainMapViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MainMapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mainMapView;

@end
```

MainMapViewController.m

```
#import "MainMapViewController.h"
#import "LocationAnnotation.h"

@interface MainMapViewController ()

@end

//Totnes Main Centre Coordinates
#define Totnes_LATITUDE 50.433741
#define Totnes_LONGITUDE -3.685797

//The Dartmouth Inn Coordinates
#define DARTMOUTH_INN_LATITUDE 50.430036;
#define DARTMOUTH_INN_LONGITUDE -3.683873;

//Pub Offers Co-Ordinates

#define TheKingBill_LATITUDE 50.431379
#define TheKingBill_LONGITUDE -3.685495

#define TheSevenStars_LATITUDE 50.431045
#define TheSevenStars_LONGITUDE -3.682945

#define TheLordNelson_LATITUDE 50.430931
#define TheLordNelson_LONGITUDE -3.683644

//Span
#define THE_SPAN 0.01f;


@implementation MainMapViewController

@synthesize mainMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Set Delegate
    mainMapView.delegate = self;

    //Create the region
    MKCoordinateRegion myRegion;

    //Centre
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centre;
    centre.latitude = Totnes_LATITUDE;
    centre.longitude = Totnes_LONGITUDE;

    //Span
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;
    span.longitudeDelta = THE_SPAN;

    myRegion.center = centre;
    myRegion.span = span;


    //Set The Map View
    [mainMapView setRegion:myRegion animated:YES];


    //Annotation

    NSMutableArray * locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    LocationAnnotation * myAnn;

    //The King Bill Annotation
    myAnn = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"The King Bill"
                                          andSubtitle:@"Another Pub In Town"
                                        andCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(TheKingBill_LATITUDE, TheKingBill_LONGITUDE)
                                                andID:1];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    //The Seven Stars Annotations
    myAnn = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Royal Seven Stars Hotel"
                                          andSubtitle:@"Hotel In Town"
                                        andCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(TheSevenStars_LATITUDE, TheSevenStars_LONGITUDE)
                                                andID:2];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    //The Lord Nelson Annotations
    myAnn = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"The Lord Nelson"
                                          andSubtitle:@"Great Pub In Centre of Town"
                                        andCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(TheLordNelson_LATITUDE, TheLordNelson_LONGITUDE)
                                                andID:3];
    [locations addObject:myAnn];

    [self.mainMapView addAnnotations:locations];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];

    int annId = ((LocationAnnotation *)annotation).idNumber;
    annView.pinColor = (annId == 1) ? MKPinAnnotationColorPurple
                                    : (annId == 2) ? MKPinAnnotationColorGreen
                                                   : MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    return annView;
}
```

Comment: Do I put this in my LocationAnnotation.m ?

Comment: I want to set each annotation individually so I can pick its colour.

Comment: But what should I do with all my other information that I currently have like the title, subtitle, longitude and latitude. Idealy I would like to just add the code to my current code that I have. Is there not a way of doing that and adding another property?

Comment: For your properties you just have to use your LocationAnnotation class in place of my MapViewAnnotation class and setting your parameters. Just move your annotations declaration from your LocationAnnotation class to your ViewController class (I guess you have one).

Comment: I also have another view controller using the LocationAnnotation class so it is hard to move all of it around. I will add all of my code so you can see. Thanks for your help by the way!!!

Comment: Don't forget to add the CoreLocation & MapKit frameworks to your project.

Comment: Okay so i am getting close. I have also added core location frameworks into my project but I now get this error! 2013-04-09 13:51:17.857 Totnes[1389:907] -[MKUserLocation idNumber]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ddf7fd0 (lldb)..... The pins are loading up and I can see them and that they are different colours but the map behind isn't showing up and it appears to crash the app.

Comment: I've changed your MainMapView to mainMapView, did you connect this value (and removing the old one) with your map on your storyboard ?

Comment: Yes I have changed this but still have the error and I also imported core location into my LocationAnnotation.h and MainMapViewController.h

Comment: I have updated my code below to show you how it currently looks now implementing your code and the Core Location. Maybe you can spot the problem in that?

Comment: I've added this "if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;" to viewForAnnotation method.

Comment: Okay next problem... Now that I have changed the LocationAnnotation file, my other map that also links to this file has problems and won't load. If I put the .h & .m will you take a look at it for me? I need to be able to add a pin that I can change the colour for, preferably using the same code you used before. I will add it below in a new answer. Thanks, R